# How to build a short out of char(s) in Python using bit shift?

Tags: python, bit-shift

I have two char 8 bit values that I need to combine to build a short 16 bit value.

In C++, I would do it like this:

```
unsigned char lower = <someValue>;
unsigned char upper = <anotherValue>;
unsigned short combined = lower + (upper << 8);
```

How can I do likewise in Python v2.6.2?

It appears it will just be the same in Python, but I want to make sure there isn't some subtle difference:

```
lower = <someValue>
upper = <anotherValue>
combined = lower + (upper << 8)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work the same.

Comment: I always did this and never had a problem. The only thing to keep in mind is that python's integers aren't fixed length, so some "tricks" might not work as expected.

Comment: It works the same, but what you end up with is not really a short, but a Python integer. e.g. if `upper` value was actually greater than 255 then the final result won't actually fit in 16 bits, and Python won't complain. You might want to add `& 0xffff` to it to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be slightly overkill, but if you want to be really sure to avoid any hidden difference, I advise to fall back to C using  [ctypes](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/ctypes/index-3.html)  :

```
lower = ctypes.cschar(<somevalue>)
upper = ctypes.cschar(<anothervalue>)
combined = ctypes.csshort( lower + (upper << 8) )
```

Doing so, you have the advantage of having hard-typed your variable, which will make debugging easier in the future.

NB : I'm not really sure if the << operator still works with ctypes ( there is no reason not to ) .